# Unity update 5.4.1 assembly reference bugs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, using

I just updated my unity to 5.4.1. I can play normally in the engine itself, but when i build my game i get errors like these:

> The type or namespace name `NetworkBehaviour' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
>
> The type or namespace name `UI' does not exist in the namespace` UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> The type or namespace name `IPointerUpHandler' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

and there are lot of them, as you can see most of them are from standard assets.

all using directives are in scripts. I dont know what to do. i think it's bug maybe? and now i should wait to next update? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: has you first installed Unity 5.4 beta?

Comment: no i just went to unity update page and downloaded new update

Comment: Try deleting C:\ProgramData\Unity\index-local.xml and restart Unity.

if not the only way is reimport all Assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same problem, I fixed it with `Assets` -> `Reimport All`

**Edit**: It is a well know [Issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unexpected-compilation-errors-about-missing-ui-module-thrown-when-building-project-to-standalone-after-project-upgrade) of Unity, if that doesn´t work, try deleting the `Library\UnityAssemblies` folder. After restarting Unity, the folder will appear and probably will fix your problem.

Comment: It is a well know issue of unity, [link](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unexpected-compilation-errors-about-missing-ui-module-thrown-when-building-project-to-standalone-after-project-upgrade), if that doesn´t work, try deleting the  Library\UnityAssemblies folder and dont forget to make a backup.

Comment: Ormeno, is it safe?

Comment: Yes, just delete the folder and restart unity and a new UnityAssemblies will be there.

Comment: Yes, I was freaking out because my Puppet2D asset had stopped compiling. I deleted the entire folder and re-imported the asset from the store and voila, no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

some of your assets are probably still set up for an earlier version of Unity. reimporting your assets may help out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I updated unity from version 2018.3.11f1 to 2019.1.0f2 and I tried all the fixed I could find on the internet, what SOLVED it is just by deleting "Drive:\UnityProjects\Project_Name\Packages\manifest.json" file and restarting unity.

Try Reimporting assets from "Unity:-Assets->ReimportAll" see if it works for you.